# IMAP: keep junk out of INBOX

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, email

I have mail system properly configured. Spam mails are tagged as expected but they all fall into INBOX. Now I need them to go directly into the INBOX.Junk folder. How this can be done?
ps. I have osx 10.6 server.

**EDIT**:
I need it to be done on server side (not client) for every user account.
os x 10.6 server.

Answer (score 0):

Select the INBOX.Junk mailbox, and in the menu, choose *Mailbox > Use Mailbox For > Junk*

Comment: (or similar, I'm not on a Mac right now)

Comment: it may be good if you use POP. But not with IMAP and many various email clients working on the same account at the same time. I've edited my question.

Comment: @spajak If you're doing server-side email filtering (e.g. SpamAssassin), you can configure that accordingly and your clients don't even need to know, except for better presentation/categorization. If you want the clients to filter, you need to tell them where to move the detected files. That's how you do it in Apple Mail. AFAIK, there is no such thing as a universal spam folder in IMAP; as there is e.g. the INBOX folder for new incoming email.